# UITableViewControler push to another TableViewController Graphical Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I made simple push from UITableViewController to another UITableViewController and while pushing, it makes graphical issue, one tableview covers another. After 1sec of finished pushing, New TableView looks normal, but it's annoying, and it must be fixed. The issue does not occur, when i use push UITableViewController to UiViewController with tableview, but i need to use static tableview, so i must push from UITableViewController to UITableViewController.

[image]
Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the normal push animation from viewController to viewController. It looks like your viewControllers have a transparent background.  Try setting your backgrounds to a fully opaque color to see if that addresses the issue.

Comment: This is the best resolution https://github.com/travisjeffery/TRVSNavigationControllerTransition

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a custom background, use `UITableView`'s `backgroundView` property. Do not set anything on your `UIWindow` and make your table view's background transparent. This will not work in many cases. You will also get issues when animating cells in and out.